# Compilation with dependency to maven-model fails

Tags: maven

I want to read the pom information at runtime.
Since `maven-jar-plugin` writes into a sub-sub-folder of META-INF the `pom.xml`,
I thought this should be possible,
with the following snippet of code:

```
import org.apache.maven.project.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader;
import org.apache.maven.project.Model;
...
String pomFile = "META-INF/maven/xxx/yyy/pom.xml", 
Url url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(pomFile);
MavenXpp3Reader reader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
Model model = reader.read(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```

Here, `xxx` and `yyy` are group and artifact id in pom.
To be sure that the dependencies are ok, I even added to the pom

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
      <version>${versionMvn}</version>
    </dependency>
```

with version 3.6.3.
In my $home/.m2/repository, i can see the correct jar.
Nevertheless, compilation fails with message

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project latex-maven-plugin: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /home/ernst/OpenSource/LatexMavenPluginGit/maven-latex-plugin/maven-latex-plugin/src/main/java/eu/simuline/m2latex/core/MetaInfo.java:[3,40] package org.apache.maven.project.io.xpp3 does not exist
[ERROR] /home/ernst/OpenSource/LatexMavenPluginGit/maven-latex-plugin/maven-latex-plugin/src/main/java/eu/simuline/m2latex/core/MetaInfo.java:[4,32] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Model
[ERROR]   location: package org.apache.maven.project
```

which means that the failure occurs already in the imports.
What is really strange: whereas for class `Model` the package itself is found,
and only the class itself is not found,
for `MavenXpp3Reader` not even the package seems to be found.
I also tried `mvn -X install`, but all seems ok.
Who can help?

Comment: Which information from the POM do you need?

Comment: There several other opportunities to read the needed information ...and of course as @JFabianMeier asked: Which information do you need?